# How to use SUMIF with the criteria as text within a string

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I have column A that has dates in the "8-Oct-2021" format, I have column B that has numbers I want summed.

```
=SUMIF(A2:A, "*Oct*", B2:B)
```

I currently have the formula above, with the criteria as `"*Oct*"` because there's text before and after the 'Oct'. I have other months so I want each month added up.

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B, A2:A, ">="&DATE(2021,10,1), A2:A, "<="&DATE(2021,10,30))
```

Above does the trick, but I'd like to keep it simple with the first formula. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you have **numbers** in range `A2:A`, **not text**, because the dates in GS are numbers, so your formula `SUMIF()` will return 0.

You can shorten your `SUMIFS()` formula to `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(month(A2:A), 10, B2:B))`  or to `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(text(A2:A, "mmm"), "Oct", B2:B))`